# collisions between two imageView Android

Tags: java, android, collision-detection

I'm trying to detect collision between two `ImageView` components.

Here is the collision code I have written so far:

```
ImageView iconBall;
ImageView iconBloc;
Rect rectBall = new Rect();
Rect rectBloc = new Rect();

textCollide = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCollision);
iconBall.getHitRect(rectBall);
iconBloc.getHitRect(rectBloc);
collision = rectBall.intersect(rectBloc);

textCollide = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCollision);
iconBall.getHitRect(rectBall);
iconBloc.getHitRect(rectBloc);

if (Rect.intersects(rectBall,rectBloc)) {
    textCollide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textCollide.setText("coucou y a collision fdp");
    collision = true;
    Game.this.finish();
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this part of code:

```
textCollide = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCollision);
iconBall.getHitRect(rectBall);
iconBloc.getHitRect(rectBloc);
```

What you have in the if condition is enough,
You can check pixels coordinates while running your app by enabling display touches on developer options in your phone.